# Where is Unity Fabric verions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, version, google-fabric

I want check Unity Fabric's verion which insatalled in my project.
I not found it in Website, Unity project folder, Unity Menu, Unity Inspector window.
Wherever Fabric version?

Answer (score 1):

Paul from Fabric here. You can check which version of our Unity plugin is installed by going to the Fabric menu, then choosing "Prepare Fabric". From there, you should see the version of Crashlytics that has been installed.

Comment: Thank you for save my time!